# 2 playstation network accounts and a game

Tags: ps4, psn

if I have two psn accounts on my ps4 and I bought a game on my #2 account which doesn't have PS plus, will I be able to play that game on my #1 account with multiplayer?

Comment: knowing that my first account has PS plus

Comment: short answer, no. Long answer, you can through sharing, but PSN subscription is also shared. This has been asked, before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Make sure your ps plus enabled account has the PS4 set to the default PS4 for that account

Instructions on how to do that are here
[Activate as your primary PS4](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/activation.html)